# Geth Installation stopped: PC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc

Tags: go-ethereum

Look the picture :)
Why this is not working ? Its stopped

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the logs, it seems you are trying to run geth node and the --datadir parameter in the command has an incorrect value.

Below is the sample command to run geth node, change the parameter values as per your use case.

```
geth --mine testnet/genesis.json --datadir testnet/ --rpc --rpcaddr="0.0.0.0" --verbosity=2 --maxpeers=0 --rpccorsdomain="http://localhost:3000" console
```